# Referencing ComplexType Elements within ComplexType/Sequence Elements in XSD

Tags: soap, xsd, wsdl, complextype

I am trying to construct a xsd file (inside a WSDL) to get data from a SOAP Request. I have the expected soap Request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <m:upsertEntity xmlns:m="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss">
        <eTimeRequest>
            <ObjectType>String</ObjectType>
            <Action>String</Action>
            <eTimeID>String</eTimeID>
            <OperativeID>String</OperativeID>
        </eTimeRequest>
    </m:upsertEntity>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Here is what I have tried. You can not have a `<xs:ComplexType>` within another one. I have tried the referencing approach, but apparently, when I tried to do a SOAP Request with it, it was invalid. What can I do?

Here is the XSD within the WSDL:

```
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss">
        <xs:element name="eTimeRequest" type="eTimeRequest"/>
        <xs:complexType name="eTimeRequest">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ObjectType" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Action" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="eTimeID" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="OperativeID" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:element name="upsertEntity" type="tns:upsertEntity"/>
        <xs:complexType name="upsertEntity">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" type="eTimeRequest"/> <!-- These should be the ObjectType, Action, eTimeID and OperativeID in here -->
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

    </xs:schema>
```

**EDIT**
Another thing I noticed in the code I linked was that I used the `Type="eTimeRequest"` and not `ref="eTimeRequest"`.  No matter though, still invalid. Here is the error message I get on validation:

Invalid XML schema: ''eTimeRequest' must refer to an existing element.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for those who have read this. I obviously made a mistake in my XSD code, and wasted time doing so.

It's true,  `<xs:ComplexType>` is **NOT ALLOWED** in `<xs:ComplexType>`, but `<xs:Element>` containing `<xs:ComplexType>` **is allowed** in `<xs:ComplexType>`. The original SOAP Request generated was therefore invalid. I ran the new version through our system and it worked.

The Correct XSD Schema in the WSDL should have read:

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss">
    <xs:element name="upsertEntity" type="tns:upsertEntity"/>           
    <xs:complexType  name="upsertEntity">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="eTimeRequest">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ObjectType" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Action" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="eTimeID" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="OperativeID" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>           
</xs:schema>
```